# Send data to renderer process

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using `"electron": "^4.1.4"` and I am getting my data via `knex` from an sqlite3 db.

I tried to send the data via an ipcMain call. Find below my `main.js`

```
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require('electron')

// require configuration file
require('dotenv').config()

// database
const knex = require('./config/database')

// services
const {
  ScheduledContent
} = require('./service/ScheduledContent')

require('electron-reload')(__dirname);

let mainWindow

const contentService = new ScheduledContent(knex)
ipcMain.on('content-edit', async (e, args) => {
  console.log("content-edit - Backend");
  let res = await contentService.getAllContent()
  event.sender.send('content-edit-res', res)
})

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('./public/index.html')

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
```

My `renderer.js` looks like the following:

```
const {
    ipcRenderer
} = require('electron')

console.log("loaded renderer.js 123")


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', pageLoaded);

function pageLoaded() {
    console.log('The page is loaded');
    ipcRenderer.send('content-edit', 'x')
}

ipcRenderer.on('content-edit-res', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
})
```

I tried to get the data in the frontend when the page is loaded, then I wanted to append it to my `<table id="table1">`-tag within my `index.html`

However, I do not get any data in the frontend.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now, the problem with code...

```
 // event in receive, not e... 
 ipcMain.on('content-edit', async (event, args) => {
   console.log("content-edit - Backend");
   let res = await contentService.getAllContent()
   event.sender.send('content-edit-res', res)
 })
```

But, as additional information, you also can send data to renderer process with [`webContents`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) of window.

```
 const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
 let win = new BrowserWindow(<your configs>);
 win.webContents.send('message', 'Hello from main!');
```

You can find useful information [here](https://medium.com/@kahlil/how-to-communicate-between-two-electron-windows-166fdbcdc469)